# Issue with actual data visualization on thingsboard widget

Tags: thingsboard

I tried to fetch weather data from openweathermap using api call on thingsboard using rule chain rest api call. successfully I fetched all data, but I am facing issue with visualizing that data on timeseries widget card on dashboard. Issue is data which are shown on timeseries widget contains brackets.

Here by I am attaching an image of dashboard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnWc9.png)

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: there is a data converter on menu. maybe you can do something from there your data to fetch.

Comment: Can you help me out with data converter?

Comment: sure. how can we do this ?

Comment: Thankyou so much for your kind helping hand but i did resolved the issue.